# Run Varnish probe on port that's different from the main backend port

Tags: node.js, nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl, health-monitoring

I'm using varnish to load balance between two servers and I have set up a director and two backends which are doing this successfully.

My problem is my two backends are running `nginx` on port `80` listing for `my.domain.com`. Nginx then reroutes my request to a process listening on port `3000`. My process has a route called `/healthcheck` which I would like to use for the varnish backend probe.

This is currently what my `.vcl` file looks like:

```
backend b0 {
        .host = "53.243.15.198";
        .probe = { 
                .url = "/healthcheck";
                .timeout = 34 ms; 
                .interval = 1s; 
                .window = 10;
                .threshold = 8;
        }
}
```

So if I navigate to `my.domain.com/healthcheck` I get a `200 OK` but when varnish initiates the request `nginx` doesn't pick it up since it's no longer originating from `my.domain.com`.

I've tried this based on [this documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/BackendPolling) but it **Doesn't work**:

```
 backend b0 {
            .host = "53.243.15.198";
            .probe = { 
                    .request =
                         "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1"
                         "Host: 53.243.15.198:3000"
                         "Connection: close";
                    .timeout = 34 ms; 
                    .interval = 1s; 
                    .window = 10;
                    .threshold = 8;
            }
    }
```

---

How can I health check my instances without running into this problem? Or in other words is there some way to query a different port then the main one for the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to send healthcheck to `nginx`. However, your probes must have a HTTP Host `my.domain.com`  :

```
backend b0 {
        .host = "53.243.15.198";
        .host_header = "my.domain.com";
        .probe = { 
                .url = "/healthcheck";
                .timeout = 34 ms; 
                .interval = 1s; 
                .window = 10;
                .threshold = 8;
        }
}
```